# AJAX doesn't work for "flag" field print in node.tpl

Tags: 7, flags

In node.tpl I use this code:

```
<?php print flag_create_link('prova', $node->nid); ?>
```

Flag links work fine, but JavaScript toggle not. The flag link doesn't change to "Unflag link" after click.
Any idea?

Why put me on hold? What's not clear about that?

---

Update

At moment I solved with views. Set view full content node and set "Ajax" and "Flag refresh" under Other settings of views.
In original node view the problem remains.

Answer (score 2):

It might be too late to add the required JS in the node template.
Try adding your flag link to `hook_preprocess_node` in template.php instead.

e.g

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  $vars['flag_link'] = flag_create_link('prova', $vars['node']->nid);
}
```

then in your node template

```
<?php print $flag_link; ?>
```

Comment: Thx. I tried but again doesn't work Ajax